# Using LIKE clause when formats are different

Tags: sql, sql-like, netezza

I was given a patient list with names and I am trying to match with a list already in our database and am having troubles given the format of the name field in the patient list. This list is taken from a web form so people can input names however they want so it does not match up well.

| WEBFORM_NAME | PATIENT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | SMITH,JOHN L |
| SHANNON BROWN | BROWN,SHANNON MARIE |

Is there a way to use a LIKE clause in an instance like this? All I really need is the LIKE clause to find the first name because I have joined on phone number and email address already. My issue is when households have the same phone number and email address (spouses for example) I just want to return the right person in the household.

Comment: Trying to figure out parts of a name as being "first" or "last" name is a path to sorrow.  Not all names are two "words" separated by a space.  Consider Eddie Van Halen (2 words in last name) or Zack de la Rocha (3 words in last name) or Jerry Lee Lewis (2 words in first name).   Don't forget hyphenates like Olivia Newton-John or apostrophes like Sinead O'Connor.  You are not going to have a consistently accurate way to do this task based on patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if all you need is to get first name, here is the WIldCard expression to get first name

```
SELECT LEFT(WEBFORM_NAME,CHARINDEX(' ',WEBFORM_NAME)-1) AS FirstName1,
SUBSTRING(PATIENT_NAME,CHARINDEX(',',PATIENT_NAME)+1,(CHARINDEX(' ',PATIENT_NAME)-CHARINDEX(',',PATIENT_NAME))) AS FirstName2
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This seems to be making the assumption that a name is two strings of nonblank characters separated by a space.  This falls apart when the name is Eddie Van Halen or Zack de la Rocha or Jerry Lee Lewis or Mary Ann Mobley.

Comment: ok, then what about use
SUBSTRING(PATIENT_NAME,CHARINDEX(',',PATIENT_NAME)+1,LEN(PATIENT_NAME)) AS FirstName2
then use FirstName2 like 'FirstName1%'

Comment: That will give you "SHANNON MARIE BROWN" which won't match the WEBFORM_NAME of "SHANNON BROWN".

Comment: ok, then if MARIE is a middle name, do you have a list about middle name?

Comment: I'm agree that it's hard to figure out which part is FirstName, which is LastName, can't do one pattern for all conditions.

Comment: in WEBFORM_NAME it would always be the first word and it PATIENT_NAME it would always be the first word after the comma. So I parsed out first name from WEBFORM_NAME using SUBSTR(WEBFORM_NAME,0,INSTR(WEBFORM_NAME,' ')) AS FIRSTNAME1 but I need to figure out how to parse it out from PATIENT_NAME. Basically start with the first character after the comma and pull to the first space.

Comment: that's what I did in the answer, could you check it? I used Sql server

Answer (score 0):

The assumption here seems to be that the webform (where user would manually) type in the name would be of the format `<First Name> [<optional middle Name(s)>] <Last Name>`, where as the data stored in the table are of the form `<Last Name>,<First Name> [<optional middle Name(s)>]`. Its not an exact science, but since other criteria (like email, phone etc) have been matched best case

```sql
select * 
from webform w, patient p
where
  -- extract just the last name and match that 
  regexp_like(p.name, 
         '^' || 
         regexp_extract(w.name, 
            '([^[:space:],][[:space:],])*([^[:space:],]+)', 1, 2))
  and -- extract the first name and match it
    regexp_like(p.name, 
         ',[[:space:]]*' ||
                   regexp_extract(w.name, '(^[^[:space:],]+)'))
```

Since webform is free form user input, its hard to handle abbreviated middle name(s) and other variations so using the above will do first name and last name based matching which in addition to the matching you are already doing should help.